# Leaflet.JS marker goes on coords on opposite map

Tags: leaflet

not exactly sure how to word this, but when i place a leaflet marker that is east of the (i believe) 64 lat mark it goes on a map to the left. i want to make it so all the markers go on the same map.

image on what i'm talking about:
[image: map image]

i want to make it so the markers to the left go to the latitude and longitude marks they need to be at where every other marker is. you can see i draw an arrow to show where that is

what i have tried:

i can't find anything so i tried setting *worldCopyJump* to false. i then tried true and it did not fix this.

thanks!

(oh and if i zoom into the area it should be at it does not appear.)

code:

HTML:

```
<div id="mapid" style="width: 100%; height: 950px;"></div>
```

JS

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid', {worldCopyJump: true}).setView([51.505, -0.09], 3);

        L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=api_key', {
        /*maxZoom: 7,*/
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
            'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
        id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
        tileSize: 512,
        zoomOffset: -1,
        //set following lines to false
    }).addTo(mymap);

    

    var presentIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'giftmarker.png',

    iconSize:     [38, 60], // size of the icon
    iconAnchor:   [12, 57], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location

});

L.marker([65.585848, -171.011122], {icon: presentIcon}).addTo(mymap);
```

L.marker x60 times

Answer (score 1):

You need to add 360 to the `Lng` of the wrong placed markers.

So the marker should look like: `L.marker([65.585848, 188.988878], {icon: presentIcon}).addTo(mymap);`

With this code you can chage all existing markers. I take the break at -149 lng to swap the markers to the other side:

```
map.eachLayer((layer) => {
    if (layer instanceof L.Marker) {
        if (layer.getLatLng().lng <= -149) {
            var latlng = layer.getLatLng();
            latlng.lng = latlng.lng + 360;
            layer.setLatLng(latlng);
        }
    }
});
```